# How can you solve for cosx in $480 cos^2(x) - \frac{36}{cos^2x} -339 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $cosx$

$$480 cos^2(x) - \frac{36}{cos^2x} -339 = 0$$

I am doing exercice online and I have never solve this type of polynomial before. thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: set $y=\cos^2(x)$ and multiply through by $y$

Comment: $$At^2 + \frac{B}{t^2} - C = 0 \implies At^4 - Ct^2 + B = 0.$$  This is a quadratic equation in the variable $(t^2)$, so any negative roots of $(t^2)$ must be rejected.

Comment: $cos^2(x)=0.8$ - you should check and finish.

Comment: @Mufasa Thank you!